# The complexity of checking for short cycles in a graph

Tags: graphs, time-complexity

In general, the problem of finding a Hamiltonian cycle is NP-complete (Karp 1972; Garey and Johnson 1983, p. 199).

Next, as for determining the existence of long cycles, I don't hold much hope for efficient algorithms. However, what about short cycles? For instance, 3-cycles, 4-cycles, and so on. For a $k$-cycle, at what value of $k$ does the algorithmic complexity transition from polynomial time to non-polynomial time? Is there a clear boundary?

Comment: You can expect that the complexity be polynomial of a degree that grows with $k$. Though my opinion is not authoritative, I don't think that you will observe a transition.

Comment: I had posted an answer, but I’ve deleted it. $\Theta(n^k)$ would be for $k$-cliques, not $k$-cycles. Duh!

Comment: OK, @PålGD, I’ve restored it… with a mod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem of finding a simple $k$-cycle is FPT, which means that there exists an algorithm running in time $O(f(k) \cdot n^{O(1)})$.

[Alon, Yuster, Zwick (Color coding, JACM 1995)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/210332.210337) give an algorithm for exact $k$-cycle in expected time $O(k! \log k \cdot n^\omega)$.

They also give an algorithm with worst case time $2^{O(k)} nm$ or $2^{O(k)} n^\omega$.

[Fomin, Lokshtanov, Panolan, and Saurabh (JACM 2016)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2886094) give a $O(2.619^k n^{O(1)})$ for finding a $k$-cycle.

As you can see, when $k$ approaches $n$, this looks more and more like an $c^n$ algorithm.

The best known randomized algorithm for detecting hamiltonicity is $O(1.657^n)$ by [Björklund (SIAM J Computing, 2014)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/110839229), and to the best of my knowledge, the best algorithm for deterministic Hamiltonian Cycle is the $O(2^n n^2)$ algorithm by Bellman.

Answer (score 5):

If your graph has $n$ vertices and you’re interested in $k$-cycles, then a brute-force inspection will look at each of the $n \choose k$ possible $k$-tuples. Thus, assuming that $k$ is small—in other words, that $k = O(1)$—that approach is $\Theta(n^k)$.